# Access ArrayList in separate class extends by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-broadcast

i developing a project where i need to access an arrayList in separate class. i have NumberListActivity Activity where i create a list,and i want to acess this list in SmsLock class which is extends  by BroadcastReceiver. in SmsLock  class i initialize a ArrayAdapter and assign that list to the ArrayAdapter. but it encounter a problem. Please any one help me..
List Class is here.
NumberListActivity.java

```
public class NumberListActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences preferences1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor1;
    int count1 = 0;
    ListView numList1;
    Button btnAdd1;
    public static ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    public static final String Place1 = "placeKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_list);

        preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("Place1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        spEditor1 = preferences1.edit();
        count1 = preferences1.getInt("count1", 0);
        if (count1 > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
                list1.add(preferences1.getString("Value1[" + i + "]", ""));
            }
        }
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Item);

        numList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Smslist);
        btnAdd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
        numList1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        numList1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count1 = preferences1.getInt("count1", 0);
                // if (count > 0) {
                for (int i = position; i < count1; i++) {
                    // list.add();
                    if (i < count1)
                        spEditor1.putString(
                                "Value1[" + i + "]",
                                preferences1.getString("Value1[" + (i + 1)
                                        + "]", ""));
                    spEditor1.commit();

                }
                // }
                list1.remove(position);

                count1 -= 1;
                spEditor1.putInt("count1", count1);
                spEditor1.commit();
                // preferences.edit().remove(position);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        btnAdd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                spEditor1.putString("Value1[" + count1 + "]", edit.getText()
                        .toString());
                spEditor1.commit();
                list1.add(preferences1.getString("Value1[" + count1 + "]", ""));
                count1 += 1;
                spEditor1.putInt("count1", count1);
                spEditor1.commit();
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

i want the above list in this class
SmsLock.java

```
public class SmsLock extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Context c;
    String phoneNumber;
    String senderNum;
    EditText my;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NumberListActivity.list1);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {

            Toast.makeText(context, adapter.getCount() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (senderNum.contains(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }

            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smscalllocker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.smscalllocker.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.smscalllocker.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.smscalllocker.NumberListActivity" >
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name="com.example.smscalllocker.SmsLock" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat.

```
03-31 05:05:45.010: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:45.010: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:45.100: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5411): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-31 05:05:45.110: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cc9a000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:61
03-31 05:05:45.130: E/(5411): Can't open file for reading
03-31 05:05:45.130: E/(5411): Can't open file for reading
03-31 05:05:45.220: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d540000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:65
03-31 05:05:47.913: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d9d8000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:68
03-31 05:05:47.963: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:47.963: D/Activity(5411): Activity.onPause()
03-31 05:05:47.963: D/Activity(5411): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-31 05:05:47.963: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:48.023: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:48.023: V/LGMDMManager(5411): gLN(NULL)
03-31 05:05:48.063: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5411): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-31 05:05:48.073: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5de70000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:71
03-31 05:05:48.073: D/EditText(5411): EditText.onWindowFocusChanged(), Tap gesture sensor is disabled
03-31 05:05:48.073: D/EditText(5411): EditText.onWindowFocusChanged(), Tap gesture sensor is disabled
03-31 05:05:48.123: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e208000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:77
03-31 05:05:48.133: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5cc9a000 size:3768320
03-31 05:05:48.133: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d540000 size:3768320
03-31 05:05:48.133: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d9d8000 size:3768320
03-31 05:05:48.374: D/Activity(5411): Activity.onstp[()
03-31 05:05:48.374: D/Activity(5411): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-31 05:05:48.434: D/memalloc(5411): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cc9a000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:54
03-31 05:06:04.790: W/dalvikvm(5411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dcb1f8)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.smscalllocker.SmsLock: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2104)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at com.example.smscalllocker.SmsLock.<init>(SmsLock.java:22)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2099)
03-31 05:06:04.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5411):     ... 10 more
```

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue if this approach would be feasible or not, but then there are two things you could try:

1.Create a singleton class where you `get` and `set` the arraylist. The class might look like this:

```
Class MySingletonClass {
   private static MySingletonClass obj = new MySingletonClass();
   private  static ArrayList<String> listHere;

   public MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return obj;
   }

   // getters and setters for listHere.
}
```

To access the list you could write:

```
MySingletonClass.getInstance().getListHere();
```

`getListHere` is the name of the getter method and before getting it set it. Else you might get `NPE`.

Also a receiver might start before the list is filled. So always check for null before you use it.

2.The other option is you store the list in a cache object like

```
LruCache<String, Object> obj = ... // create a new obj (again in a singleton class)
obj.put("keyhere", list_obj_here);
```

Check for `null` even in this case in the broadcast receiver before using it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sir i have no idea of singleton class, Sir If you help me in my code because once i access that list but after that it show a problem...

Comment: a singleton class is just like every other class, and its just that only one instance of it is used since  it is static. :).. try checking for null in the receiver. it shud work i think, u might not have to change your code